# C# ASP How can i change the dataSouce ID of a datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i change the Datalist DatasourceID?

I am using c# with a ASP datalist bound to a datasource with DataSourceId="DataSource1"

I have an OnCommandclick event with the following code:

```
    protected void DataList4_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime sessionExpiry;
        string getCompany, strCompany, getUser = GetID.userSession();
        Label myLabel = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("EpicLabel");
        string strEpic = myLabel.Text;
        sessionExpiry = DateTime.MinValue;
        strCompany = GetData.companyName(strEpic);
        SetItem.cookie("SetAddEpic", strEpic, sessionExpiry);

        switch (e.CommandName)
        {
            case "RatingWatchList":
                if (getUser != "0")
                {
                    SetItem.cookie("SetAddEpic", strEpic, sessionExpiry);
                    SetItem.cookie("SetAddCompany", strCompany, sessionExpiry);
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "JsStatus", 
                                 "AddWatchListItem();", true);
                }
                else { ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), 
                    "JsStatus", "errorMessage('Please log in to use this 
                                              function!');", true); }
                break;

            case "RatingAddAlert":
                if (getUser != "0")
                {
                    SetItem.cookie("SetAddCompany", strCompany, sessionExpiry);
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "JsStatus", 
                                                    "AddAlert();", true);
                }
                else { ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), 
                      "JsStatus",   
                      "errorMessage('Please log in to use this function!');", true); }
                break;
        }
    }
```

but i need to change the datasource without removing the DataSourceID from the ASP datalist so i cannot use c#

```
 DataList1.datasource="NewQuery";
 DataList1.DataBind();
```

because the command buttons do not work when you remove the DataSourceID.

Comment: you can update DataSource1.SelectCommand property.

Answer (score 0):

Your Datasource should show up in your HTML so you can go to the HTML part of the page and change the ID there

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dataSourceIdHere" runat="server">
```

Comment: I have resolved this with the following code:'       
                string sessionId = GetID.userSession(), strSQL = "SELECT  dbo.Ratings.ID, dbo.Ratings.Company, dbo.Ratings.OldRatring, dbo.Ratings.NewRating, dbo.Ratings.OldTarget, dbo.Ratings.NewTarget, dbo.Ratings.RatingAgency FROM dbo.View_PortfolioRatings";
                this.SqlDataSource3.SelectCommand = strSQL;
                DataList4.DataBind();'

Answer (score 0):

Update **DataSource1.SelectCommand** property and it will update DataList if datasource is already assigned.

Comment: I got it partially working using this:                      'this.SqlDataSource3.SelectCommand = "SELECT [OldTarget] FROM [Ratings] where [Epic] = 'LLOY.L'";' but i want to add a variable to the where clause:                 this.SqlDataSource3.SelectCommand = "SELECT  [OldTarget] FROM [Ratings] where [Epic] = "  + strEpic; when i try this it throws an error.

Comment: as you are comparing with string variable, you need to put string variable between single quotes. Try this: SELECT [OldTarget] FROM [Ratings] where [Epic] = '" + strEpic +"'

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but i need to change this dynamically at runtime so on a button click it changes but if i use DataList1.DataSource = DataQuery; i have to remove the datasourceID from the ASPX (HTML) page which stops the datalist on command event from working.